# Top N rows by group using python datatable

Tags: python, r, py-datatable

What is the proper way to query top N rows by group in [python datatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable)?
For example to get top 2 rows having largest `v3` value by `id2, id4` group I would do pandas expression in the following way:

```
df.sort_values('v3', ascending=False).groupby(['id2','id4']).head(2)
```

in R using `data.table`:

```
DT[order(-v3), head(v3, 2L), by=.(id2, id4)]
```

or in R using `dplyr`:

```
DF %>% arrange(desc(v3)) %>% group_by(id2, id4) %>% filter(row_number() <= 2L)
```

Example data and expected output using pandas:

```
import datatable as dt
dt = dt.Frame(id2=[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], id4=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], v3=[1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3])
df = dt.to_pandas()
df.sort_values('v3', ascending=False).groupby(['id2','id4']).head(2)
#   id2  id4  v3
#1    2    1   3
#3    2    1   3
#4    1    1   3
#2    1    1   2
```

Comment: What is wrong with your example code? Also do you mean `DataFrame`?

Comment: @Dan nothing is wrong except that it won't scale, thus my question for datatable solution. I mean `datatable` not `DataFrame`, added link in question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from `datatable` version 0.8.0, this can be achieved by combining grouping, sorting and filtering:

```
from datatable import *
DT = Frame(id2=[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 
           id4=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           v3=[1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3])

DT[:2, :, by(f.id2, f.id4), sort(-f.v3)]
```

which produces

```
     id2  id4  v3
---  ---  ---  --
 0     1    1   3
 1     1    1   2
 2     2    1   3
 3     2    1   3

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Explanation:

- `by(f.id2, f.id4)` groups the data by columns "id2" and "id4";
- the `sort(-f.v3)` command tells `datatable` to sort the records by column "v3" in descending order. In the presence of `by()` this operator will be applied within each group;
- the first `:2` selects the top 2 rows, again within each group;
- the second `:` selects all columns. If needed, this could have been a list of columns or expressions, allowing you to perform some operation(s) on the first 2 rows of each group.